# Magento: cannot override resource model. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: magento

So I would like to override Mage_Rating_Model_Resource_Rating_Option_Vote_Collection class.

do following:

```
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        <models>
                <rating_resource>
                        <rewrite>             
                             <rating_option_vote_collection>Mycompany_Modulename_Model_Resource_Rating_Option_Vote_Collection</rating_option_vote_collection>
                        </rewrite>
                </rating_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

I tried also this one:

```
   <config>
        ...
        <global>
            <models>
                    <rating>
                            <rewrite> 
                                 <resource_rating_option_vote_collection>Mycompany_Modulename_Model_Resource_Rating_Option_Vote_Collection</resource_rating_option_vote_collection>
                            </rewrite>
                    </rating>
            </models>
        </global>
        ...
    </config>
```

I get false on

> Mage::getResourceModel('modulename/rating_option_vote_collection')

anyway.

What could be wrong here?

PS: cache is turned off.

Comment: Be careful because code is correct now! It has been fixed after posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT: Added relevant information from this answer to the question]

Oops, my bad.
My fault was in

```
Mage::getResourceModel('modulename/rating_option_vote').
```

The correct code is:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('modulename/rating_option_vote_collection');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you pasted, as you didn't put any `...` inside the `<model>` tag, your model's alias is not defined, so calling it with `Mage::getResourceModel('modulename/rating_option_vote')` can't work.
try:

```
   <config>
        ...
        <global>
            <models>
               <modulename>
                   <class>Mycompany_Modulename_Model</class>
               </modulename>
                <rating>
                    <rewrite> 
                         <resource_rating_option_vote_collection>Mycompany_Modulename_Model_Resource_Rating_Option_Vote_Collection</resource_rating_option_vote_collection>
                    </rewrite>
                </rating>
            </models>
        </global>
        ...
    </config>
```